# submit a html form in a popup window

Tags: html, forms

I have a html form with this submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="upload_invoice" value="Upload Invoice" onclick="window.open('upload_customer_invoice.php','','height=400,width=400'); return false;">
```

i want the form to submit as normal but in a popup window.

this works okay, but its not posting any data

my form tag looks like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

how can i make the form submit as well as open in a popup window

Comment: Use `onsubmit` in the form, rather than `onclick` in the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the 'target' for a form. Below is a sample Java Script solution, it can be done different ways.

```
document.forms['yourForm'].setAttribute("target", "yourPopUp");
window.open('url', 'yourPopUp', 'height=400,width=400');
document.forms['yourForm'].submit();
```

Comment: please post your relevant code (HTML + JavaScript) and we will get it to work.